# Get parent value from json using jq

Tags: json, jq

My json file looks like this;

```
{
 "RQBTYFE86MFC3oL": {
    "name": "Nightmode",
    "lights": [
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "7",
      "8",
      "9",
      "10",
      "11"
    ],
    "owner": "kvovodUUfn2vlby9h9okdDhv8SrTzkBFjk6kPz2v",
    "recycle": false,
    "locked": false,
    "appdata": {
      "version": 1,
      "data": "QSXCj_r01_d99"
    },
    "picture": "",
    "lastupdated": "2018-08-08T03:21:39",
    "version": 2
  }
}
```

I want to get the 'RQBTYFE86MFC3oL' value by doing a query for 'Nightmode'. So far I came up with this;

```
jq '.[] | select(.name == "Nightmode")'
```

This will return me the correct part of the Json but the 'RQBTYFE86MFC3oL' part is stripped. How do I get this part as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to determine the key name(s) corresponding to values satisfying a certain condition is to use `to_entries`, as explained in the jq manual.

Using this approach, the appropriate jq filter would be:

```
to_entries[] | select(.value.name == "Nightmode") | .key
```

with the result:

```
"RQBTYFE86MFC3oL"
```

If you want to get the key-value pair, you'd use `with_entries` as follows:

```
with_entries( select(.value.name == "Nightmode") )
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input JSON is too large to fit comfortably in memory, then it would make sense to use jq's streaming parser (invoked with the --stream command-line option):

```
jq --stream '
  select(.[1] == "Nightmode" and (first|length) == 2 and first[1] == "name")
  | first | first'
```

This would produce the key name.

The key idea is that the streaming parser produces arrays including pairs of the form: [ARRAYPATH, VALUE] where VALUE is the value at ARRAYPATH.

Answer (score -3):

You want to get the Key Value.

So use the keys command, to return 'RQBTYFE86MFC3oL' as that is the key, the rest is the value of that key.

```
jq 'keys'
```

Here is a snippet: https://jqplay.org/s/YvpCb2PH42

Reference: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/